# how can i setup an aws lambda function to run my java script code in an especific time period

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I have a java script code that uses puppeteer to do some changes in a website, i want to schedule this code to run in lambda in especific time periods, i have already tried to find some tutorial about this but havent find any especificly about this topic.

Comment: You can schedule actions (execute lambda function) with EventBridge https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of cloudwatch rules/cron to trigger lambda in periodic manner.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html